# Computing $P(X = 0)$ for the following mixed variable (discrete and continuous)?

Tags: random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

I've been given the following distribution:

$F_X(x) = \frac14 e^x $ if $x < 0$ and $ 1 - \frac14 e^{-x} $ if $x \geq 0$

I have not had any teaching on mixed variables as of yet. The question asks me to compute $P(X = 0)$. How do I go about doing this? I was thinking of doing something like $F_X(0) = P(X < 0) + P(X = 0) = F_X(0^-) + P(X=0)$ but I'm not sure what the LHS should equal: $\frac 14$ or $\frac 34$.

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct.  You evaluate $F_X(0)$ according to what you are given, for $0\geq0$ so $F_X(0) = 1 - \frac{1}{4}e^{-0}= 3/4$. In general the probability mass at a point is equal to the discontinuous jump in the CDF.

Comment: Recall also that all CDF functions are right-continuous, as this one is.

Comment: @Michael Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To calculate $P(X=0)$ simply evaluate the "jump" you have in $F_X(0)$ that is $3/4-1/4=1/2$